# Create pyramid checkerboard matrix MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix

I'd like to create a pyramid shaped checkerboard on a white background.  It needs to be a large matrix (1186,686) or I would just do it manually.  A simplified version of what I'm after is below:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0
0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0
0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0
1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1
```

Comment: What is the intended behaviour for even column counts? For example 6x6?

Comment: I'm not following your question

Comment: Could you show us the expected output for some pyramid that has # of columns as `8` or `10` or just any even number?

Comment: Ah.  Now I see.  The pyramid would just be off center then.

Comment: Off to the right or left? Adding expected output to your question would help us understand I think.

Comment: You are absolutely right Divakar.  It doesn't matter to which direction it would get shifted, just so long as if I used the same command, the resulting matrix with new dimensions would be shifted the same direction.  So, in short, let's do left.  :D

Comment: @user3753314: Please put an example to your question. What is the correct answer for 3x4? `[0,1,0,0;1,0,1,0;0,1,0,1]` or `[0,0,0,0;0,1,0,0;1,0,1,0]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an attempt, it is half-vectorized since I could not figure out how to do this without a for-loop yet.

```
function B = board(rows, cols, centerright)
    c2 = cols/2;
    mid = floor(c2);
    if c2 ~= int32(c2) || centerright
        mid = mid + 1;
    end

    B = zeros(rows,cols);
    for row = 2:min([rows, mid+1, cols-mid+2])
        offset = row-2;
        newr = zeros(1, cols);
        newr([mid-offset:2:mid+offset]) = 1;
        B(row,:) = newr;
    end
end
```

Demo:

```
>> board(6,9)
ans =
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     1     0     1     0     0     0
     0     0     1     0     1     0     1     0     0
     0     1     0     1     0     1     0     1     0
     1     0     1     0     1     0     1     0     1
>> board(6,10,0)
ans =
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     1     0     1     0     0     0     0
     0     0     1     0     1     0     1     0     0     0
     0     1     0     1     0     1     0     1     0     0
     1     0     1     0     1     0     1     0     1     0
>> board(6,10,1)
ans =
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     1     0     1     0     0     0
     0     0     0     1     0     1     0     1     0     0
     0     0     1     0     1     0     1     0     1     0
     0     1     0     1     0     1     0     1     0     1
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed thanks.  There's one issue with it though: If the width is not large enough to complete the pyramid, it errors.  Is there a way to tell it to stop once the width of the function = the width of the matrix?